# Facebook4j: how can I check if logged in user likes a certain post?

Tags: facebook-like, facebook4j

I am using Facebook4j. Can anyone tell me how I can find out if the logged in user has liked a certain post?

Many thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: there is a method called getPostLikes that gets all the likes of a post...i dont know what should be done after that